# Reputation cap for highly-upvoted posts

Tags: support, reputation

Today I posted an answer on Physics SE which has received a fair amount of attention. However, the reputation increase stopped after about 20 upvotes. I’m not exactly sure how the reputation system works — is this an intended feature? It’d also be neat to see a general list of what actions correspond to which increases/decreases of reputation.

Comment: Yes, there is a cap on rep earned on a specific question per day. I've hit it once or twice. Sad but true.

Comment: If you hit the rep cap enough times you get a badge to honour your achievement!

Comment: It's to prevent people from rocketing up in reputation from, say, posting a witty one-liner that gets 100 votes because of the HNQ.

Comment: Relevant: [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32160)

Comment: It is all on the help page: https://physics.stackexchange.caom/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @NorbertSchuch You spelled the link wrong. It should be physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @Chris Thanks.  Wonder how the a got there ...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is intended. You can earn at most 200 reputation through upvotes in a single UTC day. The reputation through accepted answers is not affected by this.

Comment: It's worth noting that bounties are not included in this either (though they were in the past).